# How to Control Click Event Of A Textbox Array?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using *VB 2010*. I have 20 `TextBox` controls in my form. I turned them to `TextBox` array.

Here is the code:

```
Dim TbArray(19) As TextBox
Private Sub Form7_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
      ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    TbArray(0) = TextBox1
    TbArray(1) = TextBox2
    ...
    TbArray(19) = TextBox20
```

It works properly. I want my program to select all the text on the `TextBox` control which got focused.

How can i know which `TextBox` control has been selected? I mean there is no `Private Sub TbArray(i)_GotFocus` in the dropdown menu of vb designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expound on what Akram said,

```
For x = 0 to 19
   AddHandler tbarray(x).GotFocus, AddressOf TextBox_GotFocus
Next x

Private Sub TextBox_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim tb As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    tb.SelectAll()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle the [TextBox.GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx) event of all the `TextBox` controls using one event handler method. Use the following:

```
Dim focusedTextBox as TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
```

Comment: do i write it for all the TextBox gotfocus part? i have 20 Textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the text inside the TextBox to get highlighted when it gets focus? Sounds like a job for JavaScript to me. Should be fairly simple using jQuery or something similar

Comment: Yes i want highlighted. But im not using java